# MSSQL Get latest Dataset from multiple Entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a MSSQL-Table and i want to query the latest dataset for each user.

This is the table.

id = BIGINT AI NN

user =  varchar(50) NN

status  =  TEXT

insertDate = GetDate()

| id | user | status | insertDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | ok | 2023-01-13 08:11:03.290 |
| 2 | ross | Not OK | 2023-01-13 08:11:27.667 |
| 3 | rachel | Not OK | 2023-01-13 08:13:37.850 |
| 4 | rachel | OK | 2023-01-13 08:21:48.727 |
| 5 | test | OK | 2023-01-13 08:53:31.440 |
| 6 | ross | OK | 2023-01-13 09:12:50.930 |

And the result should be

| id | user | status | insertDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | rachel | OK | 2023-01-13 08:21:48.727 |
| 5 | test | OK | 2023-01-13 08:53:31.440 |
| 6 | ross | OK | 2023-01-13 09:12:50.930 |

I have tried this code

```
 select *, 
  
  (select MAX(id) maxId from table b WHERE a.user = b.user Group By b.user)
  from table a
```

but i get all Entries instead only the last entries.

thanks in advance

Comment: *"status = TEXT"* I *hope* you don't mean the `text` data type; `text` has been deprecated since **2005**. Are you *really* likely to have a status that is over 8,000 characters in length as well? That seems unlikely.

Comment: You need to use JOIN or at least IN within the outer query (or of course, this could also do using window functions), otherwise your subquery has no effect. There are lots of duplicates for this question. Did you google this before creating your question?